# yo angular projectname Command

Tags: angularjs, npm, yo

I am running this command and getting continous error one after one.
Module is not there.I install that module and it is showing next module is not there.For example:One of the module error--->>

> Error: Cannot find module 'shelljs'
>      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
>      at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>      at require (module.js:380:17)
>      at Object. (/home/bele/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/generator->angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/actions/user.js:2:13)
>      at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>      at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>      at Module.require (module.js:364:17)

Comment: how did you setup the project? did you run all the installation steps? `npm install`, `bower install`, `grunt`? I'm not sure if this is part of the `yo` project setup or if you have to run it manually.

Comment: http://yeoman.io/codelab/setup.html following this tutorial

Comment: I used  npm install --global generator-angular@0.11.1

Answer (score 0):

could be an old verison of yo installed

`npm cache clean && npm upgrade -g yo`

Comment: did you install the angular generator with "-g"?

Comment: npm install --global generator-angular@0.11.1

Answer (score 0):

To be on the save I'd also update all involved tools: 
`npm update -g npm yo bower grunt`.

Sometimes bower can't download all dependencies at the first time and it's required to run `bower install` again.